# How to map two arrays at the same time HTML, ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, axios

Looked at some similar questions but none were applicable here. I want the IDList to be updated whith every iteration, for every iteration timeSlot iterates 10 times giving the same ID to 10 values.

How would i go about making these iterate at the same time?

```
    const timeSlot = [
    ["07:00-08:30"],
    ["08:30 - 10:00"],
    ["10:00 - 11:30"],
    ["11:30 - 13:00"],
    ["13:00 - 14:30"],
    ["14:30 - 16:00"],
    ["16:00 - 17:30"],
    ["17:30 - 19:00"],
    ["19:00 - 20:30"],
    ["20:30 - 22:00"]

  ]

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/api/get/week1").then((response) => {
      setIDList(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [IDList, setIDList] = useState([]);

 const renderTableData = () => { 

    return (
      <tr>
        {IDList.map((val) => (
            <td>
                 {timeSlot.map((n) => (
              <button id={val.id}> {n} {val.id}</button>
                 ))}
            </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    );
  };
```

Comment: is IDList and timeSlot array length same?

Comment: no,  IDlist has numeric values 1-70 i would like each value in timeSlot getting a unique id. So in practice 07:30-08:00 would be repeated 7 times with id's 1, 11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61

Comment: how about declare let i=1;
and inside `timeSlot.map` do i++?

Comment: that worked like a charm, i'm sorry for bothering with stupid questions im totally new to this hehe